# Can't change the permissions of files/folders on a volume with Docker windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows

I tried to change the permissions of files/folders on a volume with Docker windows.  But the permissions are not changed, unexpectedly.

Environment:
Host: Windows 10 Pro
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4

Step to reproduce:

1. Build a image with the Dockerfile below.
2. Run a container with a volume.
3. Change the permissions of files/folders.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
CMD [ "powershell" ]
```

Outputs:

```
D:\data\docker\sample>docker build -t sample .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.272GB
Step 1/2 : FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
 ---> 2cddde20d95d
Step 2/2 : CMD powershell
 ---> Running in dd207fe8b262
 ---> e0203df155cd
Removing intermediate container dd207fe8b262
Successfully built e0203df155cd
Successfully tagged sample:latest

D:\data\docker\sample>docker run -d --name sample --mount type=volume,source=sample_volume,target=C:/data sample ping -t localhost
5a21f41d63de321e912ec3b99010a062d2e04d5f99145c6cd8bf649d3fbbebf1

D:\data\docker\sample>docker exec -i sample cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>cd c:\data
cd c:\data

c:\data>MKDIR foo
MKDIR foo

c:\data>ECHO hoge > foo\hoge.txt
ECHO hoge > foo\hoge.txt

c:\data>cacls foo
cacls foo
c:\data\foo NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(ID)F
            BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(ID)F
            CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(ID)F
            BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(ID)R
            BUILTIN\Users:(CI)(ID)(special access:)
                                  FILE_WRITE_DATA
                                  FILE_APPEND_DATA
                                  FILE_WRITE_EA
                                  FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES



c:\data>cacls foo\hoge.txt
cacls foo\hoge.txt
c:\data\foo\hoge.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(ID)F
                     BUILTIN\Administrators:(ID)F
                     BUILTIN\Users:(ID)R


c:\data>cacls foo /T /E /G everyone:F
cacls foo /T /E /G everyone:F
processed dir: c:\data\foo
processed file: c:\data\foo\hoge.txt

c:\data>cacls foo
cacls foo
c:\data\foo NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(ID)F
            BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(ID)F
            CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(ID)F
            BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(ID)R
            BUILTIN\Users:(CI)(ID)(special access:)
                                  FILE_WRITE_DATA
                                  FILE_APPEND_DATA
                                  FILE_WRITE_EA
                                  FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES



c:\data>cacls foo\hoge.txt
cacls foo\hoge.txt
c:\data\foo\hoge.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(ID)F
                     BUILTIN\Administrators:(ID)F
                     BUILTIN\Users:(ID)R
```

I found a document which says that the permissions of files/folders on volumes cannot be changed on Linux containers.  But I could not found documentation about Windows containers.  Does Windows containers support the permission changes of file/folders on a volume **on Windows containers**?

Link:

- Logs and troubleshooting | Docker Documentation https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#permissions-errors-on-data-directories-for-shared-volumes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the link that you mentioned in question, it seems that docker for windows does not support changing file permissions.

> Docker for Windows currrently implements host-mounted volumes based on
>   the Microsoft SMB protocol, which does not support fine-grained, chmod
>   control over these permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I thought it is the case of Linux container on Docker for Windows.  Are there documentations about Windows containers?

Comment: "Docker for windows" refers to all containers running on windows platform

Comment: I understand.  Thank you so much!