# Changing file permissions from a mounted file from inside the docker container (Windows 10)

Tags: docker, file-permissions

Is it possible to change the file permissions from a mounted file from inside the docker container?
And if yes how do I do that?
If I try it with chmod nothing happens.
I'm using a Debian container on windows 10.

Here's a picture of what I've tried.

[image: What I've tried]

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: What is your Docker version and are you using WSL2 with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like it is not possible based on documentation in [here.](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#permissions-errors-on-data-directories-for-shared-volumes)

> When sharing files from Windows, Docker Desktop sets permissions on shared volumes to a default value of 0777 (read, write, execute permissions for user and for group).

> The default permissions on shared volumes are not configurable. If you are working with applications that require permissions different from the shared volume defaults at container runtime, you need to either use non-host-mounted volumes or find a way to make the applications work with the default file permissions.

This has been already answered on [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597290/cant-change-the-permissions-of-files-folders-on-a-volume-with-docker-windows)